# Count total occurences with ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My request seems trivial: "retrieve the total number of occurences of one specific word in the field "words" of all the document.

The index is simple. I put only the main structure:

```
@Document(indexName = "documents")
public class Document{
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, fielddata = true, name = "words")
private List<Word> words;
}

public class Word{
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true)
    @NotBlank private String data;

    //...other fields
}
```

I'm using the Elasticseatch API for Java.

The only solution I found is to iterate over the returned list of SearchHit, and sum the totalHits of each item.

But this solution is too exprensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) to achieve the result you want.

> Note: Loading field data in memory can consume significant memory.!

```
PUT test_content/_doc/1
{
  "content": "first test"
}

PUT test_content/_doc/2
{
  "content": "second test"
}

GET test_content/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content",
        "size": 1000000
      }
    }
  }
}

GET test_content/_mapping
PUT test_content/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true,
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**When you run this you will get the following error:**

> illegal_argument_exception Fielddata is disabled on [] in []. Text
> fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [content] in order to load field
> data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use
> significant memory.

If it's a one-time or rare operation you can enable it.

#### Note that the result you see below is the document count that contains the relevant word. For example, there are 2 words containing the word "test". This means that even if the word "test" occurs more than once in the same document, it will be counted as one.

[image]

Comment: If doc1 has words: ["A", "B", "A"] and doc2 has words: ["A"], and I serach for "A", the result I want is: 3.

Comment: Unfortunately, Elasticsearch does not provide a built-in feature to count the total occurrences of a specific word across all documents. You might need to use a custom script or an external tool to achieve this.

Comment: really?? To me it seems a common request.

Comment: yes for real... :)

Comment: What concrete solution do you suggest?

Comment: Ask chatGPT to write a custom Python script to provide the count of the total occurrences of a specific word across all documents.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
   BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        boolQueryBuilder.must(
                QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(QueryUtils.toQuery(template.getKeyword(), "words.data"))
        );

        FilterAggregationBuilder filterAgg = AggregationBuilders.filter("filter_aggr", boolQueryBuilder);
        NestedAggregationBuilder nestedAgg = AggregationBuilders.nested("nested_aggr", "words").subAggregation(filterAgg);

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(
                QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()
        );
        searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(nestedAgg);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse s = clientConfig.elasticsearchClient().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return ((ParsedFilter)((ParsedNested)(s.getAggregations().get("nested_aggr"))).getAggregations().get("filter_aggr")).getDocCount();
```